# Why is this way of calculating mean life of radioactive atoms incorrect?

Tags: radioactivity, half-life

Suppose there are $N$ radioactive atoms and the half life of decay is $t$. Then after one half life the number of remaining atoms will be $\frac{N}{2}$. And so after each half life the number will be halved.

Which means,
$1/2$ of the atoms will have a life of $t$

Half of the the remaining half or $1/4$ of the atoms will have a life of $2t$ and so on.

Then if the mean time for decay is $\tau$, then it should be:

$\tau = \frac{(\frac{N}{2}t+\frac{N}{4}2t+\frac{N}{8}3t+...)}{N}$
or $\tau = t(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+...)$

But this infinite series doesn't equal to $\frac{1}{ln2}$.
And we know that, $\tau =\frac{t}{ln2}$

So obviously my calculation is wrong. Why is this way of calculating the mean time for decay wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean life of radioactive substance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/366299/)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

> Which means, 1/2 of the atoms will have a life of t
>
> Half of the the remaining half or 1/4
> of the atoms will have a life of 2t and so on.

The corrected statement is:

> Which means, 1/2 of the atoms will have a life $\le t$
>
> Half of the the remaining half or 1/4
> of the atoms will have a life between $t$ and $2t$ and so on.

Comment: Silly me. I got it. I overlooked this simple point and some time after posting the question, I came to realize it.

Comment: A second, related problem, is that this statement is expressed as a discrete rule ("*...after each half life the number will be halved... Half of the the remaining half or 1/4 of the atoms will have a life ...*"), when the actual rule is continuous ("***...at any point in time t1>0,*** *the remaining atoms will have a half-life of t1+t*").  Even with the correction you point out above, the discrete rule would not mathematically reduce to the correct single equation (exponential decay) , but would still allow many odd step-decay solutions.

Answer (score 6):

> Which means,
>   $1/2$ of the atoms will have a life of $t$

is not a correct statement as some of them will have a lifetime of almost zero, some $\frac 12t$ some $\frac{199}{200}t$ etc, so you have overestimated the time that the atoms live.

To see how it should be done correctly read the answer to [Mean life of radioactive substance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/366299/mean-life-of-radioactive-substance/366339#366339).